# how to add a ssh key to a bit bucket account via ansible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, bitbucket, ansible

Am new to ansible.  I am trying to automate a deployment. I can do this manually. Not sure how this can be achieved via Ansible

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Found a better way to do it-

```
- name: Upload ssh key to the Instance
  copy: src=yourSrc/.ssh/id_rsa_bitbucket dest=/yourDest/.ssh/id_rsa_bitbucket mode=600

- name: Clone the git repo using GIT_SSH
  git: repolink dest=dest key_file=yourDest/.ssh/id_rsa_bitbucket accept_hostkey=true clone=yes force=yes
```